# The primitive of a discontinuous function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I'm thinking about the primitive of an arbitrary function. As we all know, every continuous function has a primitive according to the Newton-Leibniz formula, $\int_{x_0}^{x} f(x) dx$ is the primitive of function $f(x)$. However, if $f(x)$ is discontinuous, say has a point of discontinuity of the first kind, the the integral has both left and right derivative, but they don't coincide. So the question is whether we are able to find a primitive for those kind of functions. Or more generally, what kind of function has a primitive?

Comment: What you call "primitive" here is usually known as an "antiderivative" in English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To complete Henning answer, two small things:

**Darboux Theorem** States that if $f$ admits primitives, then $f$ satisfies the Intermediate Value Theorem.

This Theorem is a powerful tool to prove that certain functions cannot have primitives.

Also,

Let

$$F(x) = \cases{x^2 \cos\frac{1}{x} &  x\ne 0 \\ 0&x=0} \,.$$

Then, its derivative is

$$f(x) = \cases{2xcos\frac{1}{x}-\sin\frac{1}{x} &\text{for } x\ne 0
\\0&\text{for }x=0}$$

But the function

$$g(x) = \cases{2xcos\frac{1}{x} &\text{for } x\ne 0
\\0&\text{for }x=0}$$ is continuous, thus admits primitive.

Hence, their difference

$$g-f= \cases{\sin \frac{1}{x} &\text{for } x\ne 0
\\0&\text{for }x=0}$$  admits a primitive.

I find this example interesting since for all $-1<a <1$, the function
$$\cases{\sin \frac{1}{x} &\text{for } x\ne 0
\\a&\text{for }x=0} $$

verifies the Intermediate Value Theorem, but it only admits primitives for $a=0$ (it cannot admit primitives for two different values of $a$, since otherwise their difference would also admit primitives, thus satisfy the IVT)..

The functions which admit primitives are between continuous functions and functions which satisfy the IVT....

Comment: Good points both.

Answer (score 3):

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that *if* $f$ has an antiderivative, *then* the antiderivative equals $b\mapsto \int_a^b f(x)dx$ plus some constant. So in the case of an isolated jump discontinuity, your argument shows that there cannot be any antiderivative.

More complex discontinuities *can* allow antiderivatives, however, but to the best of my knowledge there is no nice characterization of the functions that happen to have one.

Some strange-looking specimens can be constructed by taking standard examples of a differentiable function with discontinuous derivative, such as
$$ F(x) = \cases{x^2 \sin\frac{1}{x^2} & \text{for } x\ne 0 \\ 0&\text{for }x=0}$$
and differentiating to get
$$ f(x) = \cases{2x\sin\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x}\cos\frac{1}{x^2} &\text{for } x\ne 0
\\0&\text{for }x=0}$$
which exists everywhere but is wildly discontinuous at 0.
It seems to be quite difficult to point to a property of this $f$ that would tell us that it has an antiderivative.

Comment: The validity of the first sentence may depend on context.  Derivatives are not always Riemann integrable, e.g., see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6711/integrability-of-derivatives, so one may need to go to Lebesgue or Henstock–Kurzweil.

Comment: Re: the first sentence, the FTC also requires $f$ to be (Riemann-)integrable. ($f$ having an antiderivative doesn't imply that $f$ is Reiemann-integrable. Also, not all Reieman-integrable functions have antiderivatives.)